# Wanna Make a News Section to my site with any Free HTML Editor with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I got a web site with News & Article section.i am using Access for Database.I got FCKEditor for HTML editor.I can save HTML based text to my db but i cant show it correctly in the datalist control.What i have to use for showing this saved text from DB.Datalist is a good choice ? Or where can i learn making a dynamic article&news section for my site ?

Comment: "i cant show it correctly in the datalist control": What problem do you face?

Comment: thanx i solved my problem with using table and repeater control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the HTML as you want it rendered simply assign it to the text property of a Literal control. A DataList is used to display a collection of items that you may obtain from a DB with a query.

Comment: but i am showing title and some content of my news or article first with DATAlist.

Comment: I see you've fixed your issue by switching to a table and repeater. Perhaps if you are able to include a code sample we can be more helpful next time?